# Multiple Endpoints (for replicated SOAP Servers) with SAVON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, soap, savon

I am trying to make a SOAP request to a remote SOAP Server using the Savon gem in rails. The SOAP Server is replicated on three instances with different IP Addresses, i.e. XXX.XXX.XXX.1, XXX.XXX.XXX.2 and XXX.XXX.XXX.3.

I am able to explicitly define the savon client endpoint using one of the above ip addresses like so:

```
Savon.client(
    endpoint: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.1:15043/enmac/SOAP",
    namespace: '',
    convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase,
    env_namespace: 'SOAP-ENV',
    namespace_identifier: nil,
    log: true,
    log_level: :info,
    pretty_print_xml: true,
    read_timeout: 90,
    open_timeout: 90,
    headers: {
        "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip"
    }
)
```

The problem with the above sample code is that when the SOAP Server instance with IP Address XXX.XXX.XXX.1 is down then my services goes down as well.

What I am actually looking for is an approach that will make sure that when SOAP Server instance XXX.XXX.XXX.1 is down then XXX.XXX.XXX.2 takes over etc.

Below is what I tried but couldn't get it to work properly:

1. I have a database table with all the SOAP Servers instances populated by IP address with only a single of them with a status of active
2. I have a the following method that shift to then next server:

   ```
     def shift_oms_server
         @oms_server = OmsServer.where(status: true).first
         case @oms_server.ip_address.to_s
             when 'XXX.XXX.XXX.1'
               @oms_server.update_attribute(:status, false)
               @next_oms_server = OmsServer.where(ip_address: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.2').first
               @next_oms_server.update_attribute(:status, true)
             when 'XXX.XXX.XXX.2'
               @oms_server.update_attribute(:status, false)
               @next_oms_server = OmsServer.where(ip_address: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.3').first
               @next_oms_server.update_attribute(:status, true)
             when 'XXX.XXX.XXX.3'
               @oms_server.update_attribute(:status, false)
               @next_oms_server = OmsServer.where(ip_address: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.1').first
               @next_oms_server.update_attribute(:status, true)
         end
     end
   ```
3. Now I modify my Savon Client initialization like so:

   ```
       @oms_server = OmsServer.where(status: true).first
       Savon.client(
               endpoint: "http://#{@oms_server.ip_address.to_s}:15043/enmac/SOAP",
               namespace: '',
               convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase,
               env_namespace: 'SOAP-ENV',
               namespace_identifier: nil,
               log: true,
               log_level: :info,
               pretty_print_xml: true,
               read_timeout: 90,
               open_timeout: 90,
               headers: {
                   "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip"
               }
           )
   ```
4. Finally wherever I make the SOAP Request call I will have something like a begin rescue block like so:

   ```
      begin
        # make soap server request
      rescue HTTPServerException => e
        shift_oms_server
        # make soap server request
      ensure
        shift_oms_server
        # make soap server request
      end
   ```

Forgive my English. The approach above didn't work for me. I will be happy if someone could enlighten me where I went wrong with the above approach or provide a direction to a more simpler and efficient approach.

Ideally I would like to know if it is possible to have more than one endpoints defined using the Savon gem, if yes how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Is there an error message? Is there some undesired behaviour? What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: Your `begin...rescue...ensure...end` implementation is a bit dodgy, though. Why are re-sending the SOAP request **in the `ensure` block**?? This will cause all requests to be sent at least twice. However, I can't be certain of any behaviour since you didn't provide a [mcve] of code.

Comment: Thanks @TomLord, that is exactly what is happening ... the request is sent multiple times at least twice like you just mentioned.

Comment: I have removed the ...ensure block but the code is still behaving the same. It sends the request multiple times. I was under the impression that it will only go into the rescue block when there a problem was encountered during the sending of the request. But it seems it always go into the rescue block.

Comment: It *will* only go into the rescue block when an exception is raised. Again: Can you provide a [mcve]? Exactly what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: I also don't understand what behaviour you'd expect if **all** SOAP servers go down? Logically, I'd say you should round-robin all three servers then abort; but your code's logic appears to be "try one, if that fails try a second one, then give up"??

Comment: I have fixed the code now, its working as expected [at least not as efficient or optimal ;)] .... thanks @TomLord for the advise, I needed to remove the ....ensure ...block. The reason why it was still misbehaving after the first attempt was due to some block of code doing the same thing somewhere.

Comment: For what it's worth (although I'm still hesitant to submit a proper answer without seeing a [mcve]), a better implementation would be to do something like: `attempts = 0; begin; attempts += 1; make_soap_request; rescue; shift_oms_server && retry if attempts < 3; end`